# NO reason to exercise if a virgin?

Tags: muscle-gain

My friends tell me that I am a virgin so I should not go to gym after school and workout because I won't build muscle. I am 13 years old and skinny, about 83 lbs. and 5'. I wanted to get in better shape and stronger because friends call me weak but they also tell me you cannot build strength or fitness if you are a virgin so I must have sex first. Is this true or what should I start do?

Comment: You friends are mistaken.  While it is controversial for people who have not started puberty to work out with heavy weights, this has to do with hormone levels; being a virgin has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I can't understand the reason for putting the question on hold. The claim that "you cannot build strength or fitness if you are a virgin" is clearly false, so why "opinion-based"?

Comment: Guys... surely "Sally Clithead" is a troll?

Answer (score 5):

Your friends are incorrect.  Virginity makes no difference in the results of working out.

In regards to building strength at that age, focus on building a solid foundation.  A proper diet is the most important thing at your age for getting in shape.  Sexual history/activity is irrelevant.